# Can a hotspot in Ubuntu validate wrong passwords also?

Tags: wpa2, hotspot

I want to host a hotspot in Ubuntu. The hotspot should authenticate every client, whether he enters right password or wrong password. Actually, I want to validate four way handshake even if the password entered is wrong.

I am hosting the hotspot, can I configure WPA2 like that?

Answer (score 3):

No you cannot. Ubuntu hotspot uses WPA2-PSK with a [pre-shared key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pre-shared_key) (not a password).

**Pre** in pre-shared means both parties must be supplied with the same key **before** connection takes place; both parties need to use the same key to be able to communicate with each other.

If "*the password entered is wrong*" (i.e. different than you know), it means **you will not be able to decrypt** the communication from the client.

Comment: Absolutely right, because what Ubuntu can set up quickly is a WPA2-PSK network. With WPA2-enterprise, this is perfectly possible, as demonstrated on every bigger CCC event, where everyone can pick their password randomly, since the password isn't really needed to authenticate; it's just necessary to allow encryption to be used. Again, for what Ubuntu's Hotspot dialogs offer, what your write is 100% correct.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thank you, that's a valid point. I clarified.

Comment: Question is, should we be removing the "hotspot in Ubuntu" from the question's title and replace it with "WPA2-PSK hotspot"? That might make the question more visible to future readers who might not be using Ubuntu

Comment: @MarcusMüller I would say a person who has such question and wants to ask is more keen on using less technical term. That's why duplicate questions appear (and are kept on SE) - people ask the same questions using different language.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is possible to set up a soft AP in ubuntu with tools like airbase-ng and achieve what you have described (this is known attack). I am not sure if this is something you are interested though. Also, back in the day this functionality was supported only to advertise fake WEP protected networks. I am uncertain if newer versions support it for WPA/WPA2 protected APs.